# Como traduzco algo con comillas?

Tags: angularjs

Al intentar hacer la traducción, no me coge las comillas para poder escribir dentro del **mdInput placeholder="**.
Se puedo poner a pelo, o necesito una variables (como la pondría)?

```
<input #pin type="password" mdInput placeholder="{{Password | translate}}" formControlName="pin">
```

El resultado

```
"Password": "Password555555",
```

Comment: Puedes poner lo que te sale y lo que te gustaría que te salga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que estás usando `ngx-translate`:

Cuando usas

```
{{ Password | translate }}
```

Angular asume que `Password` es un atributo del componente. Si lo que quieres es usar "Password" como clave a buscar en tu fichero JSON de Internacionalización (i18n), lo tienes que poner como un literal:

```
{{ 'Password' | translate }}
```